# PHP doesn't detect the $_POST data sent from Angular 10 client

Tags: php, html, angular, xampp

I am trying to access the $_POST data at PHP sent from the Angular 10 client. But I can't seem to access the file, as it seems to show that $_POST is empty. Here is my PHP code:

```php
<?php
    $name = $_POST['newFile'];
?>
```

the html code:

```html
<form method="POST" #ngSendFile="ngForm" (submit)='OnSubmit(ngSendFile)'>
  <div>
    <label for="newFile">Enter New Agency</label>
    <input 
        class="form-control input" 
        ngModel 
        required 
        type="file" 
        id="newFile" 
        name="newFile">
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

the function in ts code of the component:

```js
OnSubmit(form:NgForm){
    if(form.invalid) return;
    const filePath = form.value.newFile;

    let agencyObs:Observable<any>;
    agencyObs = this.fileService.sendFile(filePath);
    agencyObs.subscribe(
      (resData)=>{
        console.log(resData);
      }
    )
  }
```

and the function at service.ts file:

```js
sendFile(filename:string){
        const body = new HttpParams().set('newFile',filename);
        return this.http.post(
            environment.url+'fileupload.php',
            body
           ).pipe((err)=>{
             catchError(this.handleError);
             console.log(err);
             return err;
           }
         )
    }

    handleError(errorResponse:HttpErrorResponse){
        console.log(errorResponse);
        return throwError("Something Went Wrong");
    }
```

And the response I get is just 'null'. How can I solve this issue? I am using a XAMPP server. After this I want to conduct an actual file transfer, where I can transfer the file to ../xampp/htdocs/trail/files/

Comment: May be it will help.
https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/upload-file-using-angular-and-php-7ee12c67a28b

Comment: @NishabhMistry: While it does work if I simply copy pasted it, the solution here uses reactive forms approach. I would like to maintain the template-driven approach I have used here.